# How is momentum conserved during the short period of time during collision when there is no kinetic energy and only potential energy?

Tags: energy, work, collision, kinetic-theory

We know that in an elastic collision , momentum of the system is always conserved. But during the short period of time during collision when there is no kinetic energy and only potential energy how is momentum conserved as kinetic energy zero implies zero velocity and that using p=mv implies that momentum is zero.
I tried to think that momentum could be in terms of impulse I may or may not be right.

Comment: In my opinion, there is a misconception concerning conservation of momentum.  Total momentum before a collision equals total momentum after a collision.  There is nothing in that statement about what happens during the collision.

Comment: There is no instant during a collision in which both objects are at rest unless the total momentum is zero ( the objects come from opposite directions with equal and opposite momenta).

Comment: @David White actually I read it somewhere so the question was like is the total linear momentum conserved during the short time of an elastic collision of two balls? And the answer was yes

Comment: @R.W Bird would the kinetic energy of the center of mass mean anything physically like the total energy or does it not have any function?

Comment: @HellXWar, your question also applies to a collision between two objects that have springs attached to them.  During the time that the springs are interacting, kinetic energy is converted to spring potential energy.  Total momentum will not be conserved during this slow collision, but the springs will soon expand and convert their potential energy back to kinetic energy, restoring total momentum in the process.  Note - this assumes a totally conservative process (no frictional losses)

Comment: The only requirement for conservation of momentum is that the forces be equal and opposite during the period of contact (and no external forces). This will be true with a spring between the masses, or with an energy loss (to heat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . . . . during the short period of time during collision when there is no kinetic energy and only potential energy . . . .   implies that momentum is zero.

Think about the centre of mass of the system of the two colliding masses whose velocity does not change during the collision.
The centre of mass carries the net momentum of the system and so the system always has kinetic energy.

In the centre of mass frame the two masses have equal magnitude and opposite direction momentum ie net zero momentum, and so at an instant during the collision the masses can stop relative to the centre of mass frame and have no kinetic energy with energy stored as potential energy.

Comment: But when we find the velocity of the center of mass v=m1v1+m2v2/(m1+m2) it comes out to be zero as you said the momentum is zero so wouldn't it mean kinetic energy is zero or would we find it as the sum of individual kinetic energy?

Comment: @HellXWar The masses could ne travelling in opposite directions with a net momentum of zero.

Answer (score 0):

In a totally inelastic collision, all available energy is converted into internal energy: heat, permanent deformation, internal sound waves.

So in your problem, the point of maximum deformation--or whenever all the available kinetic energy is converted into potential energy, you have a completely inelastic collision, and that is the kinematics that exist.

For an instant, the potential energy *is* internal energy of the objects. For perfectly elastic collision, that energy is then extracted (perfectly) and sent back to the individual objects with no losses, and non (not even a phonon) retained in either.